# Can I adjust the timeout of the filter box in GTK?

Tags: nautilus, gtk

I'm running ubuntu 11.10 and I was wondering if somebody knows how to modify the timeout in gtk3 for the small "filter" box that appears when you start typing in a list / nautilus folder (in 2.x it stays up a lot, in 3.0 it acts more like kde in the way that you can almost only have 1 letter a a time).

**Update**
It's working nicely since the final release.

Comment: IIRC someone asked this question, except it was about Nautilus 2, and pretty much the comments and the answers said that this was hard coded into Nautilus and that if the user wanted to change it, said user had to compile Nautilus with his own modifications.

Comment: Any tips on what's changed ? I would recompile nautilus/gtk if the current way remains the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to compile your own changes into nautilus as I believe the functionality is hard coded (most things in nautilus are). I don't think you will be able to use a previous version either, you might have to modify the recent version and reverse the specific changes.

Of course no one is going to know what the exact changes are, that requires a lot of code investigation.

Comment: Thanks for the update, that's pretty dumb though, O well, thunar here I come.

Comment: Don't forget to +1 my post and mark the question as answered.

Comment: It's back to it's normal behavior on the final release.

Comment: Great, ad an update to your question so people will see that.